# Missing IUSR account and Asp.net account

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I got this error when i want to browse my own asp.net website through IIS manager
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
The solution for this give IUSR user permission to access(read) the web.config file.
But when i do this the IUSR account not appear on the "user and group names" in porperties windows.
I don't know what is the problem??

Answer (score 7):

**Finally** I get the solution for my problem. The asp.net account not appear in the IIS manager because I didn’t check its check Box in IIS to do this in windows 7 follow the steps

1. Open control panel
2. Click on” program” link (not uninstall programs)
3. Click” turn windows features on/off” link
4. locate” Internet Information services IIS” in the pop up window and expand its node
5. Expand the” World Wide Web Service” node
6. Expand “Application Development Features” node
7. check the check box of”ASP.NET”
8. Then click ok button

Now you will see the Asp.net account on the IIS manager and by default you see IIS account Now you should move you asp.net website from “my document” to another place the IIS have permission to access it (to any partition on your computer) Now browse your website from IIS manager .It will work well thanks a lot Jeff Turner for trying to solve my problem really thanks. – Yasmeen just now edit 
Now you will see the Asp.net account on the IIS manager and by default you see IIS account Now you should move you asp.net website from “my document” to another place the IIS have permission to access it (to any partition on your computer) Now browse your website from IIS manager. 
**It will work well thanks a lot Jeff Turner for trying to solve my problem really thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running aspnet_regiis?

open up a command prompt as administrator and cd to C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ then run

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

and see if that creates your iusr accounts. Don't forget to mark the question you asked related to this a few hours ago as answer as well.

Comment: Jeff are you sure of the syntax of the command!!
there is no command like that

Comment: This command on Framework 2 but i used 4.0 may be this the problem??

Comment: no it's on framework 4.0 also. Go to C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\ is there an aspnet_regiis.exe? if there is, then you need to go to that directory in your command prompt and run aspnet_regiis -i

Comment: No there is no any aspnet_regiis.exe!!

Comment: do you have .net framework 4.0 installed? I can't really help you if you're missing those basic components.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me find it: 
[Missing IUSR account on Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033126/missing-iusr-account-on-windows-server-2008-r2-iis7-5)

Just make sure that when you search, you go to server level on location and include all in types...